# Is there a linear time algorithm for integer multiplication verification?

Tags: ds.algorithms, randomized-algorithms

There is a [quadratic randomized algorithm for matrix product verification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freivalds%27_algorithm).

Is there a similar trick to 'verify given three integers $n,a,b$ if $n=ab$ holds?' in $O(\log n)$ time?

Comment: Should be $O(\log n)$ or else it would be exponential time.

Comment: I am a bit surprised by the downvotes. This question appears very natural to me, and my impression is that Kaminski's result (*cf* my answer) is not very well-known.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a linear time randomized algorithm, that is of complexity $O(\log n)$: *Cf* M. Kaminski, [A note on probabilistically verifying integer and polynomial products](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/58562.214082), J. ACM 36(1), pp. 142–149, Jan. 1989.

The basic idea: Instead of checking $n = ab$ *modulo* $p$ for some random prime number $p$, check it *modulo* $2^i-1$ for some integer $i$. The reduction *modulo* $2^i-1$ is fast (faster than *modulo* a prime $p$) since only additions are required. And if you take $i = O(\log^{1-\epsilon} n)$, the computation of $(a\bmod 2^i-1)(b\bmod 2^i-1)$ can be done in (sub)linear time. Kaminski proves that if $n\neq ab$, $n\not\equiv ab\bmod 2^i-1$ with high probability.

Comment: It still seems we require $(\log n)(f(n))$ at an $f(n)\in\omega(1)$ (might be at any $f(n)\in\omega(1)$) to achieve $1-o(1)$ probability of success. So to achieve $1-o(1)$ error there is no $O(\log n)$ complexity algorithm?

Comment: 'at any' gives $O(\log n)$ but 'at any' doesn't.

Comment: No, Kaminski's algorithm has a probability of failure $1/n^{O(1)}$, not a constant probability. What is not yet known is whether there exists a deterministic linear-time algorithm.

Comment: Probability of success of $1-\frac{\mathsf{polylog}(n)}{n}$ on a single trial is deterministic $O(\log n)$. But if it were even $1-\frac{2^{\mathsf{polyloglog(n)}}}{n}$ it would not be. So it depends on what $O(1)$ is. If error $\geq\frac{1}{n^{O(1)}}$ means error $\geq\frac{2^{\mathsf{polyloglog}(n)}}{n}$ we would require $\omega(\log n)$ randomized trials. So randomized in $O(\log n)$ would itself be unsolved.

Comment: I cannot make any sense of what you write. If this is the question, no we don't know any $O(\log n)$ algorithm with error probability smaller than $1/n^{O(1)}$, for instance error $1/2^n$.

Comment: This is indeed an intriguing paper. And so is https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/31846.31850 that it cites.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  One algorithm is: pick a random $k$-bit prime $p$; reduce $n,a,b$ modulo $p$, and then check whether $n \equiv ab \pmod p$.  The chance of failing to detect an error is exponentially small in $k$, and the running time is something like $O(k \log n)$ (can probably be reduced to something like $O((\log k)(\log n))$ in theory by using efficient multiplication/division algorithms).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, you're right, I got confused.  Thank you.

Comment: So to get to $o(1)$ probability of certifying inequality it needs $\Omega(\log\log n)$ trials?

Comment: @1.. No. First, $k$ needs to be at least about $\log\log n$ so that the probability of error is $<1$ in the first place. But after that, the probability is $O(2^{-k}\log n)$, thus $k=\log\log n+O(1)$ is enough to get the probability down to, say, $1/2$, in which case $\omega(1)$ trials will make the probability $o(1)$; and if $k=\log\log n+\omega(1)$, a *single* trial will already give probability $o(1)$.

Comment: By the way, it is simpler to do the test modulo *arbitrary* random $k$-bit numbers rather than just primes. Then one doesn’t have to bother with primality testing, rejection sampling, etc. Again, $k$ needs to be above roughly $\log\log n$, and then the error is something like $\rho(k/\log\log n)$, where $\rho$ is the [Dickman function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function). In particular, $k\sim c\log\log n$ for a constant $c>1$ will give error probability bounded away from $1$, and $k=\omega(\log\log n)$ will give $o(1)$.

Comment: Is there a similar complexity derandomization? What is the best derandomization we know? Randomized time complexity is $O((\log n)(\log\log\log n)f(n))$ at any $f(n)\in\omega(1)$ which is faster compared to complexity of integer multiplication.